# Does anyone know the history of the “washed process?”

Tags: farming

Where did the washed process originate and how has it developed and progressed?  And what are the different forms and variations it has taken over the years?  I have a hunch that it began in Ethiopia and am hoping to confirm my suspicions.

Comment: Just speculating... Ethiopia is arid. So, mold should not be growing on fruits while drying as a whole. I suspect a more humid place is the first invented place as a countermeasure against mold. Or, maybe high altitudes of Ethiopian mountains? I hope that we'll learn the answer soon.

Comment: Nice comment. Why don’t you like the question?

Comment: I don't know. :) I hardly “like” something. Mostly I just read, but forget to vote. Then, on one occasion browse through a lot of posts and vote for many.

Answer (score 1):

The washed process in coffee has a rich history that traces back to regions known for their coffee cultivation, such as Ethiopia and Central America. It emerged as a response to the need for cleaner and more consistent flavors in coffee beans. The process involves removing the pulp and mucilage from the coffee cherry before drying, resulting in a focus on the inherent flavors of the bean itself.

Over time, the washed process has developed and progressed through various stages of refinement. Initially, it was a relatively simple method involving pulping the cherries, fermenting them, and then washing away the residue. This helped reduce the risk of defects and inconsistencies in the beans' flavors.

As the coffee industry evolved, so did the washed process. Coffee producers began experimenting with fermentation times, water quality, and drying methods to fine-tune the flavor outcomes. The goal was to bring out unique taste profiles while maintaining the clarity and brightness associated with the washed process.

Different regions have also adopted variations of the washed process. For instance, in Ethiopia, the birthplace of coffee, the process has deep cultural roots. The Ethiopian "washed" method involves fermenting the beans in water, which gives rise to the renowned fruity and floral flavors characteristic of Ethiopian coffees.

In Central America, where the washed process gained prominence, variations emerged based on local practices and environmental conditions. Some producers focused on extending the fermentation period to enhance complexity, while others employed controlled fermentation tanks for precision.

As specialty coffee gained momentum, the washed process took on new dimensions. "Honey-processed" and "pulped natural" methods emerged, combining elements of both washed and natural processes. These variations aimed to strike a balance between flavor clarity and the fruit-forward qualities associated with natural processing.

In summary, the washed process has evolved from a rudimentary method to a complex and versatile approach in coffee production. Its development has been influenced by the pursuit of consistent flavors, regional traditions, and the desire to showcase the unique attributes of different coffee varieties. This evolution has led to a diverse range of washed process variations that continue to captivate coffee enthusiasts worldwide.

Comment: Citing some sources and providing historical dates or ranges of dates would improve your answer.